# how to make LiveWallaper for Android in Unity?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

Wanted to ask if anybody knows a tutorial about how to make live wallpaper for android in unity 4?

The only tutorial I was able to find was this one - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l0Ou4_xA_Cg

But it looks like it needs a separate plugin, that works only with unity 3.4

Thanks

Comment: You can change some lines in the asset's script to avoid the warning. But I didn't handled yet to build the live wallpaper neither with 4.0, not with 3.4 :(

Comment: See my answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36285649/create-live-wallpaper-using-unity3d/54379845#54379845

Answer (score 1):

I've recently released uLiveWallpaper - a Unity asset that makes it possible to create live wallpapers for Android using Unity 5. It is well-tested and reliable, creates projects for Android Studio, complete with placeholder code to get you started.

Check it out!

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/ulivewallpaper-develop-android-live-wallpapers-with-unity-5.375255/

Answer (score 0):

Officially LiveWallpapers not supported by Unity.

I guess best choose is get unity 3.4 from:

http://unity3d.com/unity/download/archive

and make it by AJUnity2Eclipse from the tutorial (AJUnity2Eclipse available on Unity AssestStore - 25$).