# create live wallpaper using unity3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Can anyone tell me which asset I have to use to create a live wallpaper for android using **unity3d**?   I'm using latest version of unity which is **5.3.4** .

Comment: Googling is hard: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/uni2lwp-create-live-wallpapers-with-unity-3-4-2-3-5-7-4-0-4-0-1.172275/

Comment: Your link is for unity v3.4 - v4.1. She asked for unity 5.3.4. Its different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to unity store, search for uLiveWallpaper(Indie). It costs 25$. Import it to the unity app.

Open uLiveWallpaper window by calling

Tools → Lost Polygon → uLiveWallpaper

The window consists of three tabs: “Create Project”, “Update Project”, and “About & Support”.

To start creating your live wallpaper, first, you must create a Live Wallpaper project for Android Studio. After the initial project is created, in order to reflect the changes made in your Unity project, you’ll need to update the project.

It is compatible with all unity v5 or above.

Don't forget to give proper package name else will show an error message while building the app.

Note: to build and run your live wallpaper project, you must use Android Studio. “Build”
and “Build And Run” buttons in “Build Settings” window will build a regular Unity project that is not compatible with live wallpapers.

Start Unity. Open uLiveWallpaper window and select “Create Project” tab. Select the
destination directory, select project generation options and click the “Create Project”
button.
This will generate an intermediate Eclipse project. Now, it needs to be converted intoAndroid Studio project.

Start Android Studio.
In case a “Welcome to Android Studio” splash screen appears:
Click “Import project (Eclipse ADT, Gradle, etc.)” and select the project you’ve just
created. Click OK. “Import Project from ADT” window should open. Select the
destination directory for imported project. Click Next, leave import settings as-is, click
Finish. Wait for import to succeed. You can delete the intermediate Eclipse project now, it is no longer required.

Click “File... → New → Import Project...” and select the project you’ve just created. Click
OK. “Import Project from ADT” window should open. Select the destination directory for
imported project. Click Next, leave import settings as-is, click Finish. Wait for import to succeed.

Click “File... → New → New Module... → Import .JAR/.AAR Package” and import
“LP_uLiveWallpaper.aar” library, located in “Assets/uLiveWallpaper/Libraries/”
directory inside your Unity project.

Click “File → Project Structure...” to open the “Project Structure” window.
In the “Modules” list (on the left), select the “app” module. Switch to “Dependencies”
tab. Click the green “+” button at the right side and add module dependency
“LP_uLiveWallpaper.aar”.
Finally, click OK to close the “Project Structure” window

Test if your wallpaper project builds fine by doing “Build → Rebuild Project”. If no errors
will occur, you’re all set! Otherwise, recheck previous steps.

Comment: I am not Able to purchase this. and How to create LWP with unity from scratch?